# Can't see a message form modelAndView Object in JSP representation page

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets

Good afternoon, sorry if the question has already been asked but ... I did not find the answer in those versions.
I’m studying spring by tuturial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfeCmn8NT88), trying to write a simple CRUD (I haven’t even reached to logic of the program)and i face the problem: Can't see a message form modelAndView Object in JSP representation page, IDEA tells **that cannot resolve variable.**

I understand that this may be redundant but here are all my files.

[my project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8cT9.jpg)

WebAppInitializer

```
package com.customermanager.config;


import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        applicationContext.register(WebMVCConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispacher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispacher", new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext));
        dispacher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispacher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

WebMVCConfig

```
    package com.customermanager.config;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.customermanager.*")
    public class WebMVCConfig {


    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
        public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;

        }
    }
```

CustomerController

```
    package com.customermanager.customer;


    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
public class CustomerController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView home() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("message", "hello world");

        return model;
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Manager</title>
</head>
<body>

<H1>${message}</H1>

<p>Message: ${message}</p>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

In output i dont see my message: Hello from Spring MVC

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Because it doesn't pass through the controller.

Comment: Ok, how can a make it to pass through it? To be honest i learning from video lesson and i write it according teacher's steps, but result is not the same(

Comment: your `index.jsp` must be in `/WEB-INF/views`, you are missing an `@EnableWebMvc` (although some defaults apply even without this). And your controller doesn't select a page to render. All in all I would suggest to find a different tutorial (or make sure you are exactly following the tutorial). Also please mention the fact that you are following a tutorial (and please add a link to it as well).

Comment: my index.jsp is in /WEB-INF/views, as you can see in hierarchy (added a pic)? also i added @EnableWebMvc annotation as you saggested, but results is the same (it it very simple using i think) how can I explicitly specify a page to render?

Comment: I've looked at a lot of examples (http://www.java2s.com/example/java-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/modelandview/addobject-2-11.html) but I can't find what the difference is and what I'm doing wrong. I will definitely find other lessons, but it seems to me that this simple procedure should work in any case.

Comment: First they do `new ModelAndView("index")` nor use `setViewname` you aren't using either to select a view to render. Adding `@EnableWebMvc` to an `@Controller` is iuseless it must be on an `@Configuration` class. You shouldn't have a `web.xml`.

Comment: I made changes to the code according to your advice, unfortunately IDEA still writes that cannot resolve variable (message) on the jsp page. web.xml were generated automaticaly (and it is empty, only header?)

Comment: The fact that Intellij writes that doesn't mean if won't work. Have you actually tried to run the code?

Comment: unfortunately, the same thing

Comment: What exactly isn't working or is shown in your page? How are you testing, which servlet container/version are you using.

Comment: Im using Tomcat 9